# Android input pointer not below input field

Tags: android, html, cordova

Well, this is strange, the input pointer goes from below of the input field.
I'm working with phonegap/cordova 3.6
Why is this happen?

[image: Image example]

---

EDIT

Here goes the html of this image

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div><div>ITEMS #:</div><div><input type="number" placeholder="0" min="1"></div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div><div>AMOUNT/ITEM: US $</div><div><input type="number" placeholder="0" min="1" /></div></div>
    <div class="doBid">go</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to answer this question if you provide some code. What does your XML look like, for example.

Comment: I just put it in the main question.

Comment: Ok..I'm pretty new to android so I don't actually know what's wrong. I havent used html in my applications so unfortunately I can't help you. Sorry!